# How we can compute intercept and slope in statsmodels OLS?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033980/how-compute-aic-for-linear-regression-model-in-python/45036854#45036854) I asked how to compute AIC in a linear model. If I replace `LinearRegression()` method with `linear_model.OLS` method to have AIC, then how can I compute slope and intercept for the OLS linear model?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
regr = smf.OLS(y, X, hasconst=True).fit()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, you can use the `params` attribute of `regr`, which will display the coefficients and intercept.  They key is that you first need to add a column vector of `1.0`s to your X data.  Why?  The intercept term is technically just the **coefficient to a column vector of 1s**.  That is, the intercept is just a coefficient which, when multiplied by an X "term" of 1.0, produces itself.  When you add this to the summed product of the other coefficients and features, to get your nx1 array of predicted values.

Below is an example.

```
# Pull some data to use in the regression
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
import statsmodels.api as sm

syms = {'TWEXBMTH' : 'usd', 
        'T10Y2YM' : 'term_spread', 
        'PCOPPUSDM' : 'copper'
       }

data = (DataReader(syms.keys(), 'fred', start='2000-01-01')
        .pct_change()
        .dropna())
data = data.rename(columns = syms)
# Here's where we assign a column of 1.0s to the X data
# This is required by statsmodels
# You can check that the resulting coefficients are correct by exporting
# to Excel with data.to_clipboard() and running Data Analysis > Regression there
data = data.assign(intercept = 1.)
```

Now actually running the regression and getting coefficients takes just 1 line in addition to what you have now.

```
y = data.usd    
X = data.loc[:, 'term_spread':]
regr = sm.OLS(y, X, hasconst=True).fit()
print(regr.params)
term_spread   -0.00065
copper        -0.09483
intercept      0.00105
dtype: float64
```

So regarding your question on [AIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033980/how-compute-aic-for-linear-regression-model-in-python/45036854#45036854), you'll want to make sure the X data has a constant there as well, before you call `.fit`.

Note: when you call `.fit`, you create a regression results wrapper and can access any of the attributes lists [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html).

Comment: Good. It looks X and data are equal. BTW, does the term_spread show the slope?

Comment: In this case, `X` and `data` are not equal, but close.  `X` is a subset of `data` that excludes the dependent variable, `usd`.  And in this case of multiple regression, there are two slopes because you have two `X` variables, `term_spread` and `copper`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone searching on how to get the slope and intercept of a `LinearRegression` in scikit-learn: it has [`coef_` and `intercept_` properties](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) which show this.

```
(x, y) = np.random.randn(10,2).T
from sklearn import linear_model
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x.reshape(len(x), 1), y)
lr.coef_ # array([ 0.29387004])
lr.intercept_ # -0.17378418547919167
```