# statsmodels not returning correct gradient

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I feel like I've missed something really simple that I'm sure someone will be able to correct fairly easily. I can't get pythons stats models to return the correct gradient for some reason. Here is my code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 

y_values = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

mod = sm.OLS(y_values, x_values)
fit = mod.fit()

print(fit.summary())

print(fit.params[0])
```

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061326/how-we-can-compute-intercept-and-slope-in-statsmodels-ols?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggests I am getting the correct param for the model to be the gradient but it gives me an answer of "1.2727" which I don't understand? I was expecting this to give me a gradient of "-2.0" for this example case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the line will not pass through the origin, so the formula cannot be `y = mx` but `y = mx + c` , meaning you need an intercept:

```
mod = sm.OLS(y_values, sm.add_constant(x_values))
fit = mod.fit()
print(fit.params)

[12. -2.]
```

If this helps:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x=x_values,y=y_values)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I had tried the 'add_constant' arg but it wasn't clear how to implement it from the statsmodels docs as it looks like they're adding an extra value to the X-array before constructing the model. I got there in the end using sklearn as it didn't need the extra step!

Answer (score 1):

Got there in the end with sklearn which is a bit more 'straight out of the box':

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

mod = LinearRegression().fit(x_values, y_values)
grad = mod.coef_[0][0]

print(grad)
```